# JavaDB in memory limitations Maximum number of rows

Tags: derby, data-warehouse, javadb

I have a warehouse DB which is very slow to retrieve the data because this database is in a different location.

So, I was planning to retrieve all data in single request and store the data in server using java DB.

Can anyone please tell the max number of rows limitation for Java DB when used in memory?

I want to save 1 million records.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's no max rows limitation for Derby when used in memory.

Rather, the limitation is due to the size of the Java heap.

If you are using a 64-bit JVM, you can set the Java heap size to be very large.

But, you must have that much physical memory.

Also, note that the contents of your in-memory database will disappear when you shut down your Derby application. So, the next time you run your program, you will have to re-fetch all the data from the central warehouse.